# JSONObject and JSONArray - Need to get values held in array

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have the following JSON data structure:

```
{
    "myRequest": {
    "item1": "value1",
    "itme2": "value2",
    "item3Holder": {
        "id": [
        "ID001",
        "ID002",
        "ID003",
        "ID004"
        ]
    }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to get the id values from the id [] array.

I can can get the values for item1-3, but can't separate out the id [] array values.

```
JSONObject requestObj = new JSONObject(data.trim()).getJSONObject("myRequest");

// Retrieve items from JSONObject
String item1 = requestObj.getString("item1");
String item2 = requestObj.getString("item2");
String item3 = requestObj.getString("item3");

// Retrieve all id's
JSONArray ids = requestSubObj.getJSONArray("item3Holder");

for (int i = 0; i < ids.length(); i++) {
    String id = ids.toString();
    logger.info("id : " + id);
}
```

Comment: What is `requestSubObj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should get the objects like this:

```
JSONObject item3Holder = requestObj.getJSONObject("item3Holder");
JSONArray ids = item3Holder.getJSONArray("id");
```

Also you need to call `.getString(i)` for the `ids` object

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length(); i++) {
    String id = ids.getString(i).toString();
    logger.info("id : " + id);
}
```